# Reference request: cohomology of locally compact groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, abelian-groups

I'm looking for a basic reference that discusses different versions of group cohomology $H^*(G,H)$, where $G$ is a locally compact group, and $H$ is an abelian group (say $\mathbb{Z}$ for concreteness).

In particular, I am interested in the distinction between the use of Borel cocycles vs continuous cocycles in the definition.